# Selecting Terrain Dataset by elevation in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, select, terrain

I have added the [Terrain Dataset](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=58a541efc59545e6b7137f961d7de883) to my project in ArcGIS Pro. I would like to select the areas which have an elevation above some threshold.

Eventually, I want to use this selection as a clipping mask for some other raster.

Usually I would create the clipping mask through the "extract by attributes" tool, but I don't see any columns in the Terrain attributes table that look like an elevation number.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Terrain is technically a TIN surface, I'm not sure you can do this exactly as you described. What you could do is run Terrain to Raster to create DEM. Then reclassify your raster using the range of values you want to see. Then you can convert your raster to polygon.